# Assuming Row order in a STRING_SPIT SQL Operation

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a Stored Procedure that needs to make the assumption that row order will always be the same in order to properly run otherwise I will get incorrect data.  The user supplies a string of IDs that will need to be queried, and the Stored Procedure puts this strings into a table using the STRING_SPLIT(@Parameter, ',') operation.

Is it safe to assume the strings will be place into the table in the order that they are given to the table? I created a unit test and ran it 10000 times, each time checking the order of the table and it passed. So from that I am guessing it is safe to make this assumption.

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TestOrder] @TestIDs varchar(5000)
AS

IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestNames') IS NOT NULL) BEGIN DROP TABLE #TestNames END

-- INTO #FundNames
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(value)) AS TestIDs
    INTO #TestNames
    FROM string_split(@TestIDs, ',');

ALTER TABLE #TestNames ADD RowNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1)

SELECT * FROM #TestNames

IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestNames') IS NOT NULL) BEGIN DROP TABLE #TestNames END

GO
```

Unit Test in C#

```
[TestMethod]
public void SQLOrderTest()
{
    // Arrange
    string testIds = "3, 5, 1, 10";
    string spName = "[dbo].[sp_TestOrder]";
    string ServerName = PARR_DBDataObject.ServerName;
    string DBName = PARR_DBDataObject.DBName;

    // Act 
    bool results = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        DataTable dt = SQL.QueryStoredProcedure(spName, DBName, ServerName, false, 5000,
                                             new Tuple<string, object>("@TestIDs", testIds));
        // First Row            
        if (GetRowNumber(dt, "3") != 1) results = false;

        // Second Row            
        if (GetRowNumber(dt, "5") != 2) results = false;

        // Third Row
        if (GetRowNumber(dt, "1") != 3) results = false;

        // Forth Row 
        if (GetRowNumber(dt, "10") != 4) results = false;
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(results, true);
}

private int GetRowNumber(DataTable dt, string TestIDValue)
{
    var row = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
              where r.Field<string>("TestIDs") == TestIDValue
              select new
              {
                  TestID = r.Field<string>("TestIDs"),
                  rowNum = r.Field<Int32>("RowNumber")

              };
    return row.First().rowNum;
}
```

Comment: A SQL Server is multi-threaded and data gets saved and read randomly.  The only way to get data always in the same order is to use an ORDER BY.  If you need to data retrieve i a particular order than add a column with the sequence number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  It is never a good idea to assume that data is in a particular order, unless you use `ORDER BY`.  Often small datasets that are on a single page will even consistently be ordered as you expect.  But it is still dangerous to use functionality that is documented to not be correct.

If you want to guarantee the ordering, then you can insert the records with `order by` and an ordering value.  Here is a method using recursive CTEs:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), left(@testids, charindex(',', @testids + ',') - 1)) as id,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(@testids, 1, charindex(',', @testids + ','), '')) as rest,
             1 as lev
      union all
      select convert(varchar(max), left(rest, charindex(',', rest + ',') - 1)) as id,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(rest, 1, charindex(',', rest + ','), '')),
             lev + 1 as lev
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select trim(id) as id, lev
into #testnames
from cte
where trim(id) <> ''
order by lev;  -- not really needed but handy if you have an identity column
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad2c9400ccdde99975c589f1641d339b) is a db<>fiddle.

You can retrieve them using:

```
select tn.*
from #testnames tn
order by lev;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will stay away from that assumption even with my tiny tables.